Passing JSON object to untyped REST service in SOA BPEL
I am trying to pass a JSON object to an untyped rest service by assigning a JSON payload to the request variable.
First of all assigning a JSON string '{"init":1,"store_id":1002,"last_stock_count_id":545}' to a JSON object variable 'jsonObject'

Then passing this variable to rest webservice invoke.

While testing the service, its breaking in the invoke with below error:
<messages>
    <input>
        <jsonObject>
            <json>{
   "store_id": 1002,
   "init": 1,
   "count_id": 545
}</json>
        </jsonObject>
    </input>
    <fault>
        <bpelFault>
            <faultType>0</faultType>
            <remoteFault xmlns="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension">
                <part name="summary">
                    <summary>oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException: Rest reference payload type mismatchdefault/SIOCSClearUnavailableSOH!1.0/RDSUnavailableSOH</summary>
                </part>
                <part name="code">
                    <code>null</code>
                </part>
                <part name="detail">
                    <detail>Missing comma in object literal</detail>
                </part>
            </remoteFault>
        </bpelFault>
    </fault>
    <faultType>
        <message>0</message>
    </faultType>
</messages>

